# How do I breed a Topaz dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

The newest gemstone dragon is out, the Topaz dragon.  I couldn't find anything yet about how to breed it, does anyone know?

Comment: Just to head this off at the pass, last month's dragon gave you the elements required and incubation period on the market.  Does this dragon provide the same info?

Comment: @fbueckert That was a different question, not related to the gemstone dragons.

Comment: @Fluttershy I don't play Dragonvale, so I don't know the difference.  If the same information is provided, then I don't see the use for the question.  If it's not, then it's valid.

Comment: Market seems to give the incubation period (which isn't helpful in figuring out how to breed it). Doesn't give required elements.

Comment: The previously disputed dragon (Obsidian) was not a limited or gemstone dragon. If you look at Fluttershy's answer on Meta, there was a specific exception for gemstone or limited dragons (topaz is both). There is no obvious way to determine the breeding pair for this dragon in game.

Comment: Can I just ask how to breed every frickin' dragon in Dragonvale and get ton of rep for it?? Or are they all taken?

Comment: If you check the previous questions, you'll find there isn't that much rep in play. If you play the game, you might form an opinion about which questions are valuable, and which ones are not. You are free to ask whatever questions you choose, but others are free to downvote what they perceive to be bad questions. See relevant Meta discussions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found an answer, the breeding combination is Cactus and Firefly Dragon.

Source: [Topaz Dragon - Dragonvale Breeding Guide](http://www.dragonvalebreedingguide.com/dragon/topaz-dragon/tips-hints)